# How to delimit browser agent selection for Sitecore device?

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to enter more than one browser agent type for the Browser Agent field in Sitecore Device, but none of the delimiter I've tried works, any thoughts?

When I enter a single browser agent type it works, but when I try entering more than one, for example: "Chrome,Firefox" then it fails to work.

These are all the delimiter I've tried ([],/\|&;:).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out of the box Sitecore device resolver tries to match user agent with a code:

```
return Request.UserAgent.IndexOf(agent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

So as you see there is no place for any delimeters here.

Still you can easily create your own device resolver and plugin it into the **<httpRequestBegin>** pipeline before (or instead of) the **DeviceResolver** processor

```
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DeviceResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

What you need to do within the processor is to find the proper **DeviceItem** and set it as **Sitecore.Context.Device**

```
public class MyDeviceResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        DeviceItem deviceItem = TryToMatchTheDevice();
        Context.Device = deviceItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Maras, you are correct.  I end up following Brain Pedersen's guide on his blog to achieve a more customize device resolver.
[link](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/identifying-mobile-devices-in-sitecore/)